# Is it possible put a component working as job in background in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio-player

I'm working an app music and I have a miniPlayer that has controls to handle and show songs info. Well, when I close and open again my app (with song playing), the song info disappears because the miniPlayer re-render the components. So, I'd like to put working in background as job in service when I close the app.

The component is the bottom on image

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You could store the current played song (and it's information) in AsyncStorage.

Comment: @Dan, thanks to reply. Matter fact I've thought about that. Is it the only way or best to do that?

Comment: I would use that option personally. You could also use `redux-persist` if you want to save your entire Redux store, but this too uses AsyncStorage under the hood.

Comment: Okay. I'll work on it.

Comment: Hey @Dan. You said "You could store the current played song..." ... I'm saying that I need to show on MiniPlayer the current playing song information... because when I quit app the song still playing in background but when I open app again the MiniPlayer lose info